# How to identify contacts

Tags: reporting, contact, servicecloud

I'm trying to set up some reporting in service cloud which shows the volumes of contacts/responses sent by the agents.

A little bit about how the workflow is set up internally:

- cases come in and are assigned to a queue
- work from this queue is assigned to the agents to pick up and respond to
- when an agent sends a response, the work is added back into the queue whilst waiting for a customer response.  When a customer response is received, this can be reassigned - either back to the original agent, or to another

As cases are assigned back to the main queue (or to different agents following subsequent responses), I cannot build a report based on case owner (as it changes between the initial queue and potentially multiple agents - so will be mis-attributed).  I cannot see any field we can use which can identify the volume of individual emails/contacts sent by the agents - but I'm not sure if I'm just not looking in the right report type.

Has anyone been able to set up a report (or is there a field I'm missing) which shows the outgoing volumes of contacts for agents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-report, but SOQL solution would look like this:

```
SELECT count(id), createdBy.name 
      FROM EmailMessage 
      WHERE createdDate = THIS_WEEK and ParentId != null
      GROUP BY Createdby.name
```

If your outbound emails are logged as Activities, then you can use Report Type `Activities with Cases`, Filter by `Activity.Type` and Group by `Activity Created By` to get counts

Comment: It looks like our emails are being logged as activity, and I've been able to set up a report which shows exactly what I've been looking for.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool. Glad to be of help.  As a service to the Community you should mark answer as accepted.